# Are there any Eastern-Orthodox theologians who question the historicity of, for example, Moses and Joshua?

Tags: exegesis, history, eastern-orthodox, literalism, joshua

Some of the early church fathers seem to condone allegorical interpretations of certain part of scripture (for example Gregory of Nyssa concerning God's killing of the firstborn in Egypt). Are there any orthodox theologians today who propagate an exclusively allegorical interpretation of major parts of the Old Testament narrative?

Comment: You can say that an Bible passage describes a historical event while also saying it has an allegorical interpretation. They're not incompatible. So which do you really want to know about?

Comment: I realize I should have spent more time on the question. I will edit it if possible. I want to know if there are any Eastern-Orthodox theologians who propagate an exclusively allegorical interpretation of major parts of the OT.